# Date is stored like this 0000-00-00 in database

Tags: laravel

Sometimes date stored in my database looks like this: `0000-00-00`.

This is how I store date in my controller:

```
 $add_order->current_date = date('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: @show `current_date` datatype

Comment: check your data type i think its string.

Comment: its date datatype

Comment: This is written as a statement of fact, not a question. If it also contained "it should instead look like [...]", that would make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

change the data type of your column to `timestamp`

then use this in your controller:

`$add_order->current_date = \Carbon\Carbon::now();`

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$add_order->current_date = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d);
```